# How to get clock from a webpage

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in python which must be able to run a piece of code in a defined time, using datetime, but it must use the website clock because of the small difference between my pc clock and the website clock! 
for example, if I want to set my python clock with "Clock with AM/PM in Dark theme" section in https://deepu.js.org/angular-clock/, How to do it?

I'm wondering if anyone can help me.

Comment: Thats why time zone exists?

Comment: I know, but there is a difference (milliseconds) between my pc clock and that of the website!... I want to use the website clock to remove this small difference.
The time zones are the same!

Comment: Hello! stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should show the code you already have written, since it's not a trivial task which can be done in few lines.